# How can I change language in oracle visualization cloud?

Tags: data-visualization, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

When I open oracle data visualization cloud on firefox and set the browser's language to English this is how the tool looks like:

[image: language set to English]

When I set the language to Arabic it looks like this:

[image: language set to Arabic]

It means that it's related to the browser or it takes the default language of the tool from the browser's settings.

**I need to change the language but from the tool on the cloud or on the desktop tool.** How can it be done?

Comment: Can you access the "My account" page in OAC?
[Example here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/analytics-cloud/acubi/my-account-preferences-and-groups.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need go in the classic home > open your account > the preference tab includes language settings

Answer (score 0):

DV gets the language from your browser.
The configuration classic home only works for answers